# Google Drive Share Dialog in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive sharing dialog box in an Apps Script application.  The application is deployed as a web-app and accessed via the doGet() method.  The application contains a button to share Drive files using the Google Drive sharing dialog box.
                                     The Google Drive sharing dialog box works as expected when parameter values are absent from the doGet() request.  However, when a file Id is passed as a parameter to the doGet() method, and the share button is clicked, the Google Drive sharing dialog box returns error: 
Origin 'https://xxxxxxxx-script.googleusercontent.com' is not allowed for application ID "XXXXXXXXXX".  
I am using a HTML service to evaluate the parameter values and return an array of strings to a HTML template.  I can see the file Id being included in the request to the Drive sharing dialog box function.  Why would it work as expected with out parameter values, but throw the Origin not allowed error when evaluating the parameter values?  I even tried adding the Origin URL to the trusted java script origin list in the Developer's Console and still received the same error. 
I am trying to use Google Drive UI integration to pass the file Id from Drive to my Apps Script web application.  The shareResult() function is called via client side javascript after loading the drive-share library.

```
function doGet(e){
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('htmlfile');
    var ids = e.parameters.ids;
    html.folderIds = ids;
    return html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
function shareResult(){
   var idList = folderIds.split(",");
   s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(PROJECT_ID);
   s.setOAuthToken(oauthtoken);
   s.setItemIds(idList);
   s.showSettingsDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure 'oauthtoken' is actually set? You should debug that. I bet 'oauthtoken' is actually null or not correct. You also should not instantiate the ShareClient with PROJECT_ID. Try this instead:

```
var idList = folderIds.split(",");
s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient();
s.setOAuthToken(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
s.setItemIds(idList);
s.showSettingsDialog();
```

Comment: Yes, I verified the OAuth token is valid.  When I instantiate the ShareClient with out the PROJECT_ID, the dialog box shows the loading image for a while and then returns a 500 Error.  This code works when I hard code a file Id in the idList.  The only time it does not work is when evaluating parameters through doGet() and passing them to the client side js.

Answer (score 0):

The `e` argument in the `doGet(e)` and `doPost(e)` is an object representation of an event parameter that contains information about any URL parameters. More information about the parameters can be found in the [URL Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters) section of the documentation.

You'll have to find a way to get the `fileId` on the `e` object (which most likely resides in the `e.parameters` object). Once done, based on the [Add the dialog script](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app) of the Drive API, you'll have to put it in an array and pass it when creating the `ShareClient`.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code snippets I am using to pass parameters and trigger the ShareClient dialog.  When debugging the code I can see the file Ids from e.parameters.ids in the shareResult function.

Comment: Perhaps the fields need to be trimmed after splitting? i.e. Perhaps there is a space character prefixed / postfixed on an id making it invalid.